# Command not found while using sudo [UBUNTU 19.04]

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xampp, lampp

When i try to run xampp server using the command:

```
lampp start
```

I get

`Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.3.7-1...`

`You need to be root to perform this action.`

Although when i use

```
sudo lampp start
```

I get:

`sudo: lampp: command not found`

I tried with xampp command as well, still same result.

Comment: Different `PATH` for your user and `root`? Perhaps try to provide a full path to the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will work**

```
 $ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Provided that your installation path is `/opt/lampp` **which is the default path**.
If the installation path is unknown try `which lampp` and then start from there.

Answer (score -1):

The lampp path could be incorrect, try:

./lampp start

or

sudo /pathto/lampp start